# How do I fake my location to a specific latitude and longitude on Android?

Tags: android, location

For what I am currently doing, I need to spoof my phone's location to specific coordinates. The only problem is that the location I need is not easy to spot on a map (it is in the middle of the Pacific Ocean), and all of the location spoofing apps I can find have you select it on a map, which I can't do.

Are there any apps that let me just punch in the latitude and longitude of where I want my phone to think that it is?

EDIT: To be clear, I am setting a fake location, not getting my current location. I am also not putting this in an app being written, but putting this as a separate app on my phone.

Comment: you just need  latitude and longitude?with out request to map?

Comment: Yes, all I want is setting latitude and longitude directly. If the app has a map, that's fine, but I need to be able to do that without selecting it by tapping on a map.

Comment: here is one more idea take picture with gps tags and then extract tags from photo

Comment: That won't work because I don't want to see my current location, I want my phone to think that I am somewhere else.